# numpy load raises "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'expr'"

Tags: arrays, load, numpy, attributeerror

I try to run

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from numpy import *

b= ones((3, 3))  
print b  
save('fff',  b)  
a = load('fff.npy')  
print a.shape  
print 'fertig'
```

but it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "savetest.py", line 9, in <module>  
    a = load('fff.npy')  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/io.py", line 195, in load  
    return format.read_array(fid)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 353, in read_array  
    shape, fortran_order, dtype = read_array_header_1_0(fp)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 250, in   read_array_header_1_0  
    d = safe_eval(header)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py", line 840, in safe_eval  
    ast = compiler.parse(source, "eval")  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/compiler/transformer.py", line 53, in parse  
    return Transformer().parseexpr(buf)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/compiler/transformer.py", line 132, in parseexpr  
    return self.transform(parser.expr(text))  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'expr'
```

I tried the example from [docs.scipy.org](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) it raises the same error in my terminal, but it works in my ERIC python IDE. The Internet provides no for me understandable or transferable solution at this time.

Finally,
does anyone see the error in my code or approach and is able to provide a solution for it?

Comment: Please format your multiline code and backtraces by indenting with four spaces (Ctrl-K in the editor.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you must have another file named `parser.py` somewhere in your files (the ones that Python can find). It is making it so that Python finds the wrong parser module. Look around and see if that is the case. It could be a `parser.so` file too.

Try going into an interactive session and typing:

```
import parser
print parser.__file__
```

Hopefully, that will tell you where the troublesome file is located.

Comment: There was indeed such a file in that directory. I renamed it. Now it works as it should. Thank you for making my day.

Comment: This happened to me with a file called `signal.py`

Comment: @Abramodj same thing happened to me because my file was called signal.py